# Tag links in network search page go to stackexchange.com rather than the searched-for site

Tags: bug, tags, search, stackexchange.com, broken-link

I recently discovered that the top bar on [stackexchange.com](https://stackexchange.com/) searches the entire network. For instance, if you [search for "shoes"](https://stackexchange.com/search?q=shoes&pagesize=50), you can find all the questions on the network about shoes:

[image: Shoes is apparently a Ruby package]

But if you click on one of the tags, you'll be sent to a non-existent page: https://stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/shoes. I would have expected to land a the site's tag page instead:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/shoes.

For what it's worth, this is a very minor bug and unlikely to bother too many people as I do not believe the network search is widely known. (But it's really handy and more people *should* know about it!)